# appendTo not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple slideshow, that when you click `.left`, moves and prepends the content. This seems to only affect the `last` slide:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/4CuLE/4/

```
$('.left').click(function(){
        $('.box').animate({left: '+=100'}, 100, function(){
        var $last = $('.box').last();
        if ($last.css('left') == '100px') {
            $last.prependTo('.container').before('\n\r');
            $('.box').css('left','0px');
        }
    });
});
```

However, I've tried to reverse this process with `appendTo`. This appends to ALL content:

```
$('.right').click(function(){
        $('.box').animate({left: '-=100'}, 100, function(){
        var $last = $('.box').first();
        if ($last.css('left') == '-100px') {
            $last.appendTo('.container').before('\n\r');
            $('.box').css('left','0px');
        }
    });
});
```

Would anyone know why appendTo is appending to every item, whereas prependTo is prepending to just one?

Comment: There's a difference between those two blocks of code.  The 2nd one does an `appendTo()` regardless of position.  You need to resolve that first (remove 2 lines) before you can go further.  Also, it's difficult to help without relevant markup :)

Comment: Sorry, this a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/4CuLE/4/ scrolling right does not reverse the carousal

Comment: For some reason the callback function is running when the CSS is something like 'left: -99.98` instead of `-100`, so the `if` isn't matching.

Comment: Be aware that you are animating five objects at the same time, so your complete handler for the `.animate()` function is being called five times. I think that your problem is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CuLE/5/) and now it works. Basically, I've changed your checking method, based on `ifs` that theoretically should always return true (because you're animating the five objects to the 100px, when you check if the animated property is 100px, it should return true). I don't exactly know why it fails in the first case, but in the second case, when you go right to left, you basically are moving the five elements... but leaving the '\n\r' before them, that's why the elements move to the right with each animation.

```
var $boxes = $('.box');
var max = $boxes.length;
$('.left').click(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $boxes.animate({left: '+=100'}, 100, function(){
        if (++count != max) return; //check whether is the last call to the handler
        var $last = $('.box').last();
        $last.prependTo('.container');
        $('.box').css('left','0px');
    });
});

$('.right').click(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('.box').animate({left: '-=100'}, 100, function(){
        if (++count != max) return; //check whether is the last call to the handler
        var $last = $('.box').first();
        $last.appendTo('.container');
        $('.box').css('left','0px');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's great. I thought the `\n\r' kept the space after each inline block? (Which I need for the current layout)

Comment: It is best to kept the space with CSS. I added a 2px margin for every div, so they are separated from each other. It's better not to rely on invisible text as separators. If you changed your divs to be `display: block` with `float`, you'd see those blank spaces no longer have an effect.

Comment: My last question: why `++count` in the conditional. What does that do?

Comment: It increments the value of `count` by one and then returns the new value. Then, this value is compared to `max` (which in this case, is 5). `count++`, on the contrary, increments the value of count **after** returning its value.